# Find matching object position in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

Following Problem:

I have a Array:

```
var klassen = new Array();

klassen[0] = new Object();
klassen[0]["class"] = "barbarian";
klassen[0]["con"] = "0";
klassen[0]["str"] = "0";

klassen[1] = new Object();
klassen[1]["class"] = "bard";
klassen[1]["chr"] = "0";
klassen[1]["dex"] = "0"; '''
```

And i have a function:

```
function changecs(){
    let csclass = document.getElementById("class")
    window.finden = csclass.value;
    alert(finden);

    highlight();
}
function highlight(){
    alert(finden);
    let indexzahl = klassen.indexOf('finden')
    alert (indexzahl);
}
```

This function is linked to a Html select ( i included the necessary:

```
 <div id="class-frm">
        <label for="class">Choose a Class</label>
            <select id="class" onchange="changecs()">
                <option id="default" value="default"> Optional </option>
                <option id="barbarian" value="barbarian"> Barbarian </option>
                <option id="bard" value="bard"> Bard </option>
```

My goal is it, to select something for example bard. Then i want to know the index number of "bard" which would be 1 in this example. I hope this is precise enough. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.fineIndex()`:

```js
const klassen = [{'class': 'barbarian', con: 0, str: 0}, {'class': 'bard', chr: 0, dex: 0}]

function changecs({target:{value}}){
  const itemPosition = klassen.findIndex(item => item.class == value)
  console.log(itemPosition)
}
```

```html
<label for="class">Choose a Class</label>
    <select id="class" onchange="changecs(event)">
        <option id="default" value="default"> Optional </option>
        <option id="barbarian" value="barbarian"> Barbarian </option>
        <option id="bard" value="bard"> Bard </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Do my array have to look like this ?  ```{'class': 'bard', chr: 0, dex: 0}]```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i=0; i<klassen.length; i++){
    const element = klassen[i];
    const keys = Object.keys(element);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        if(element[key] === 'bard'){
            console.log(klassen.indexOf(element))
        }
    });
    // you can use a flag and break here
}
```